# How to prevent a text input from breaking into multiple lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't fix a tweeter bootstrap typeahed's height. I've been trying to give the outer `div` a fixed width and `overflow:hidden;`  - doesn't seem to help. The input field gets bigger as I type in more text it can't fit, instead of just naturally moving the caret.
I'm using Chrome.

The outer div's css is split up into multiple places, if you could just give some clues would be really great.
This is driving me crazy already.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" data-role="tagsinput" id="searchBox"/>
```

Comment: If possible add working fiddle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it fits better for the tweeter bootstrap github forum.  Seems to be a buil-in feature of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the line from from breaking into additional lines, try adding:

```
input {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This is useful to know, but it's not helping in my case. I think it's Bootstrap stepping in at some point and messing around with the whole bunch of elements it renders to support the type-ahead. I'm not sure though, still to figure out.

Comment: OK. Will need a working fiddle to try and help more...

Comment: I've got the feeling I've posted a wrong question to be honest. It really looks like Bootstrap kicks in and stretches it downwards. I think I'll remove the question in a bit. Thanks for your effort :)